# How to make Unreal Engine 4 Full Screen (Windows Package)

Tags: windows, package, fullscreen, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm really new to the Unreal Engine 4 and I need some help, I can't find the answer on the internet so I hope someone here can help.

When I go to the Package project (Windows) when I open the game, how do I make it always and by default in full screen? So when I open the game it will be in full screen.

Is there a blueprint I can use to do this? If not and you have to program it, can you please tell me the exact location of where I have to put the code or whatever, because like I said. I am very new and barley know the interface and how to use it. (I've come from Unity)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/51623/how-to-fullscreen-packaged-build.html Tell me if it helped.

Comment: Thank you so much. That really helped me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have selected "New Editor Window (PIE)" you can press F11 to play in full screen, or you can use console command: r.SetRes [YourMonitor'sNativeRes -noBrackets]f example: r.SetRes 1920x1080f

If you choose the Standalone Game, you can use the Console Command: fullscreen

or you can go in Editor Preferences/Play/Play in New Window: Change the size to your monitor's native resolution

In Blueprint you can use the "Execute Console Command" node and type "fullscreen" for the input command, as shown in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4zIe.png)

Comment: F11 switches between windowed and borderless windowed(which isn't fullscreen). So does the alt+enter shortcut.As well as `fullscreen` command in the console. `r.SetRes 1920x1080f` does switch to fullscreen, indeed.